# I want to find weightage of top five video in laravel 7

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to find weightage of the top 5 videos where columns are:

like,views,critic_rating (feed by admin 0 to 5)

here is my code and I also want to get video_url, id and user_id for further use

```php
$user_info = DB::table('video_information')
             ->select('view','like','critic_rating','video_url','user_id','id' ,DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
             ->groupBy('view','like','critic_rating','video_url','user_id','id')
             ->limit(5)
             ->orderBy('view', 'desc')
             ->where('created_at','>=',Carbon::now()->subdays(30))
             ->get();
```

Comment: Please explain what is the problem you are facing, what have you tried already to solve and what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Actually, I want to get data as per weightage suppose that critic_rating is 5 and views is 10 and second one views 20 and critic_rating 4 so winner will be first and one more thing is that i am selecting column with id and user_id then it will count with total or not?

Comment: I am getting data so what it will be counted all the columns, including id and user_id(these all are also an integer) because we getting a count of the total.E.g according to my query select(view, like, id,user_id) so it will be like select(number1,number2,number3) so it will be all count

Comment: actually i want to get weightage except id and user_id just want to count like,view,critic_rating that solve